# JTA transaction unexpectedly rolled back for large data

Tags: mysql, spring, hibernate, transactions, jta

For large amount of data we are getting JTA transaction exception.

The exception log says :

> org.springframework.transaction.UnexpectedRollbackException: JTA transaction unexpectedly rolled back (maybe due to a timeout); nested exception is javax.transaction.RollbackException: ARJUNA016053: Could not commit transaction.
>       at deployment.wooqer.war//org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager.doCommit(JtaTransactionManager.java:1043)
>       at deployment.wooqer.war//org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:746)
>       at deployment.wooqer.war//org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:714)
>       at deployment.wooqer.war//org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:532)
>       at deployment.wooqer.war//org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:304)
>       at deployment.wooqer.war//org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:98)
>       at deployment.wooqer.war//org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
>       at deployment.wooqer.war//org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
>       at deployment.wooqer.war//org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
>       at deployment.wooqer.war//org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:689)
>       at deployment.wooqer.war//com.quepio.service.impl.ReportManagerImpl$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$90d430dc.getAllEvidencesForEvaluation()
>       at deployment.wooqer.war//com.quepio.service.impl.ReportExportManagerImpl.processReportExport(ReportExportManagerImpl.java:334)
>       at deployment.wooqer.war//com.quepio.service.impl.ReportExportManagerImpl$4.run(ReportExportManagerImpl.java:2697)
>       at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:514)
>       at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
>       at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1135)
>       at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
>       at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:844)
>   Caused by: javax.transaction.RollbackException: ARJUNA016053: Could not commit transaction.
>       at org.jboss.jts//com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.transaction.arjunacore.TransactionImple.commitAndDisassociate(TransactionImple.java:1301)
>       at org.jboss.jts//com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.transaction.arjunacore.BaseTransaction.commit(BaseTransaction.java:126)
>       at org.jboss.jts.integration//com.arjuna.ats.jbossatx.BaseTransactionManagerDelegate.commit(BaseTransactionManagerDelegate.java:89)
>       at org.wildfly.transaction.client@1.1.2.Final//org.wildfly.transaction.client.LocalTransaction.commitAndDissociate(LocalTransaction.java:77)
>       at org.wildfly.transaction.client@1.1.2.Final//org.wildfly.transaction.client.ContextTransactionManager.commit(ContextTransactionManager.java:71)
>       at org.wildfly.transaction.client@1.1.2.Final//org.wildfly.transaction.client.LocalUserTransaction.commit(LocalUserTransaction.java:53)
>       at deployment.wooqer.war//org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager.doCommit(JtaTransactionManager.java:1040)
>       ... 17 more
>       Suppressed: javax.transaction.RollbackException: WFTXN0061: Transaction is marked rollback-only
>           at org.wildfly.transaction.client@1.1.2.Final//org.wildfly.transaction.client.AbstractTransaction.setRollbackOnly(AbstractTransaction.java:96)
>           at org.wildfly.transaction.client@1.1.2.Final//org.wildfly.transaction.client.LocalTransaction.setRollbackOnly(LocalTransaction.java:149)
>           at org.wildfly.transaction.client@1.1.2.Final//org.wildfly.transaction.client.ContextTransactionManager.setRollbackOnly(ContextTransactionManager.java:94)
>           at deployment.wooqer.war//org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jta.internal.JtaTransactionAdapterTransactionManagerImpl.markRollbackOnly(JtaTransactionAdapterTransactionManagerImpl.java:100)
>           at deployment.wooqer.war//org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jta.internal.JtaTransactionCoordinatorImpl$TransactionDriverControlImpl.markRollbackOnly(JtaTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:440)
>           at deployment.wooqer.war//org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl.setRollbackOnly(TransactionImpl.java:143)
>           at deployment.wooqer.war//org.hibernate.Transaction.markRollbackOnly(Transaction.java:68)
>           at deployment.wooqer.war//org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.markForRollbackOnly(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:364)
>           at deployment.wooqer.war//org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.handlePersistenceException(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:273)
>           at deployment.wooqer.war//org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:150)
>           at deployment.wooqer.war//org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:157)
>           at deployment.wooqer.war//org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:164)
>           at deployment.wooqer.war//org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.doFlush(SessionImpl.java:1443)
>           at deployment.wooqer.war//org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:493)
>           at deployment.wooqer.war//org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flushBeforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:3207)
>           at deployment.wooqer.war//org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:2413)
>           at deployment.wooqer.war//org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcCoordinatorImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(JdbcCoordinatorImpl.java:473)
>           at deployment.wooqer.war//org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jta.internal.JtaTransactionCoordinatorImpl.beforeCompletion(JtaTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:330)
>           at deployment.wooqer.war//org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jta.internal.synchronization.SynchronizationCallbackCoordinatorNonTrackingImpl.beforeCompletion(SynchronizationCallbackCoordinatorNonTrackingImpl.java:47)
>           at deployment.wooqer.war//org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jta.internal.synchronization.RegisteredSynchronization.beforeCompletion(RegisteredSynchronization.java:37)
>           at org.wildfly.transaction.client@1.1.2.Final//org.wildfly.transaction.client.AbstractTransaction.performConsumer(AbstractTransaction.java:236)
>           at org.wildfly.transaction.client@1.1.2.Final//org.wildfly.transaction.client.AbstractTransaction.performConsumer(AbstractTransaction.java:247)
>           at org.wildfly.transaction.client@1.1.2.Final//org.wildfly.transaction.client.AbstractTransaction$AssociatingSynchronization.beforeCompletion(AbstractTransaction.java:292)
>           at org.jboss.jts//com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.resources.arjunacore.SynchronizationImple.beforeCompletion(SynchronizationImple.java:76)
>           at org.jboss.jts//com.arjuna.ats.arjuna.coordinator.TwoPhaseCoordinator.beforeCompletion(TwoPhaseCoordinator.java:368)
>           at org.jboss.jts//com.arjuna.ats.arjuna.coordinator.TwoPhaseCoordinator.end(TwoPhaseCoordinator.java:91)
>           at org.jboss.jts//com.arjuna.ats.arjuna.AtomicAction.commit(AtomicAction.java:162)
>           at org.jboss.jts//com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.transaction.arjunacore.TransactionImple.commitAndDisassociate(TransactionImple.java:1289)
>           ... 23 more
>       Suppressed: javax.transaction.RollbackException: WFTXN0061: Transaction is marked rollback-only
>           at org.wildfly.transaction.client@1.1.2.Final//org.wildfly.transaction.client.AbstractTransaction.setRollbackOnly(AbstractTransaction.java:96)
>           at org.wildfly.transaction.client@1.1.2.Final//org.wildfly.transaction.client.LocalTransaction.setRollbackOnly(LocalTransaction.java:149)
>           at org.wildfly.transaction.client@1.1.2.Final//org.wildfly.transaction.client.ContextTransactionManager.setRollbackOnly(ContextTransactionManager.java:94)
>           at deployment.wooqer.war//org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jta.internal.JtaTransactionAdapterTransactionManagerImpl.markRollbackOnly(JtaTransactionAdapterTransactionManagerImpl.java:100)
>           at deployment.wooqer.war//org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jta.internal.JtaTransactionCoordinatorImpl$TransactionDriverControlImpl.markRollbackOnly(JtaTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:440)
>           at deployment.wooqer.war//org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jta.internal.JtaTransactionCoordinatorImpl.beforeCompletion(JtaTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:337)
>           at deployment.wooqer.war//org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jta.internal.synchronization.SynchronizationCallbackCoordinatorNonTrackingImpl.beforeCompletion(SynchronizationCallbackCoordinatorNonTrackingImpl.java:47)
>           at deployment.wooqer.war//org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jta.internal.synchronization.RegisteredSynchronization.beforeCompletion(RegisteredSynchronization.java:37)
>           at org.wildfly.transaction.client@1.1.2.Final//org.wildfly.transaction.client.AbstractTransaction.performConsumer(AbstractTransaction.java:236)
>           at org.wildfly.transaction.client@1.1.2.Final//org.wildfly.transaction.client.AbstractTransaction.performConsumer(AbstractTransaction.java:247)
>           at org.wildfly.transaction.client@1.1.2.Final//org.wildfly.transaction.client.AbstractTransaction$AssociatingSynchronization.beforeCompletion(AbstractTransaction.java:292)
>           at org.jboss.jts//com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.resources.arjunacore.SynchronizationImple.beforeCompletion(SynchronizationImple.java:76)
>           at org.jboss.jts//com.arjuna.ats.arjuna.coordinator.TwoPhaseCoordinator.beforeCompletion(TwoPhaseCoordinator.java:368)
>           at org.jboss.jts//com.arjuna.ats.arjuna.coordinator.TwoPhaseCoordinator.end(TwoPhaseCoordinator.java:91)
>           at org.jboss.jts//com.arjuna.ats.arjuna.AtomicAction.commit(AtomicAction.java:162)
>           at org.jboss.jts//com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.transaction.arjunacore.TransactionImple.commitAndDisassociate(TransactionImple.java:1289)
>           ... 23 more
>   Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: could not execute statement
>       at deployment.wooqer.war//org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:149)
>       at deployment.wooqer.war//org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:157)
>       at deployment.wooqer.war//org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:164)
>       at deployment.wooqer.war//org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.doFlush(SessionImpl.java:1443)
>       at deployment.wooqer.war//org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:493)
>       at deployment.wooqer.war//org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flushBeforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:3207)
>       at deployment.wooqer.war//org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:2413)
>       at deployment.wooqer.war//org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcCoordinatorImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(JdbcCoordinatorImpl.java:473)
>       at deployment.wooqer.war//org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jta.internal.JtaTransactionCoordinatorImpl.beforeCompletion(JtaTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:330)
>       at deployment.wooqer.war//org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jta.internal.synchronization.SynchronizationCallbackCoordinatorNonTrackingImpl.beforeCompletion(SynchronizationCallbackCoordinatorNonTrackingImpl.java:47)
>       at deployment.wooqer.war//org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jta.internal.synchronization.RegisteredSynchronization.beforeCompletion(RegisteredSynchronization.java:37)
>       at org.wildfly.transaction.client@1.1.2.Final//org.wildfly.transaction.client.AbstractTransaction.performConsumer(AbstractTransaction.java:236)
>       at org.wildfly.transaction.client@1.1.2.Final//org.wildfly.transaction.client.AbstractTransaction.performConsumer(AbstractTransaction.java:247)
>       at org.wildfly.transaction.client@1.1.2.Final//org.wildfly.transaction.client.AbstractTransaction$AssociatingSynchronization.beforeCompletion(AbstractTransaction.java:292)
>       at org.jboss.jts//com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.resources.arjunacore.SynchronizationImple.beforeCompletion(SynchronizationImple.java:76)
>       at org.jboss.jts//com.arjuna.ats.arjuna.coordinator.TwoPhaseCoordinator.beforeCompletion(TwoPhaseCoordinator.java:368)
>       at org.jboss.jts//com.arjuna.ats.arjuna.coordinator.TwoPhaseCoordinator.end(TwoPhaseCoordinator.java:91)
>       at org.jboss.jts//com.arjuna.ats.arjuna.AtomicAction.commit(AtomicAction.java:162)
>       at org.jboss.jts//com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.transaction.arjunacore.TransactionImple.commitAndDisassociate(TransactionImple.java:1289)
>       ... 23 more
>   Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: could not execute statement
>       at deployment.wooqer.war//org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:115)
>       at deployment.wooqer.war//org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:42)
>       at deployment.wooqer.war//org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:111)
>       at deployment.wooqer.war//org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:97)
>       at deployment.wooqer.war//org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:178)
>       at deployment.wooqer.war//org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.NonBatchingBatch.addToBatch(NonBatchingBatch.java:45)
>       at deployment.wooqer.war//org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.update(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3198)
>       at deployment.wooqer.war//org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.updateOrInsert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3077)
>       at deployment.wooqer.war//org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.update(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3457)
>       at deployment.wooqer.war//org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityUpdateAction.execute(EntityUpdateAction.java:145)
>       at deployment.wooqer.war//org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:589)
>       at deployment.wooqer.war//org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:463)
>       at deployment.wooqer.war//org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:337)
>       at deployment.wooqer.war//org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:39)
>       at deployment.wooqer.war//org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.doFlush(SessionImpl.java:1437)
>       ... 38 more
>   Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: > Communications link failure

The last packet successfully received from the server was 89,436 milliseconds ago.  The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago.
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor304.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:488)
    at com.mysql@5.1.46//com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:425)
    at com.mysql@5.1.46//com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:990)
    at com.mysql@5.1.46//com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.reuseAndReadPacket(MysqlIO.java:3562)
    at com.mysql@5.1.46//com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.reuseAndReadPacket(MysqlIO.java:3462)
    at com.mysql@5.1.46//com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3903)
    at com.mysql@5.1.46//com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2530)
    at com.mysql@5.1.46//com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2683)
    at com.mysql@5.1.46//com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2486)
    at com.mysql@5.1.46//com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:1858)
    at com.mysql@5.1.46//com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2079)
    at com.mysql@5.1.46//com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2013)
    at com.mysql@5.1.46//com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeLargeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:5104)
    at com.mysql@5.1.46//com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:1998)
    at org.jboss.ironjacamar.jdbcadapters@1.4.9.Final//org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.CachedPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(CachedPreparedStatement.java:121)
    at org.jboss.ironjacamar.jdbcadapters@1.4.9.Final//org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrappedPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(WrappedPreparedStatement.java:537)
    at deployment.wooqer.war//org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:175)
    ... 48 more
Caused by: java.io.EOFException: Can not read response from server. Expected to read 4 bytes, read 0 bytes before connection was unexpectedly lost.
    at com.mysql@5.1.46//com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.readFully(MysqlIO.java:3014)
    at com.mysql@5.1.46//com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.reuseAndReadPacket(MysqlIO.java:3472)
    ... 61 more

>

Comment: What are your thoughts?

Comment: We observed this behavior in case of large data set which is being queried. I am very new in this, so it could be because of MYSQL connection properties with our wildfly. Where a certain timeout property can be causing this or the maximum number of connections to mysql are acquired. Please suggest what things we can check for this tye of error.